# Why is my CSS grid, the menu not taking the whole length of the row?

Tags: css, css-grid

How can I make the "Menu" div take the whole length of the row? I have defined it to take the whole row yet it stops at level3 of the grid.

[image: My CSS Grid]

My code-

```
.wrapper{
border: 1px solid black;
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit,minmax(100px,1fr));
grid-template-rows: 40px auto 40px;
/* grid-auto-rows: auto; */
grid-gap: 5px;
background-color: chartreuse;}

.wrapper > div{
font-size: 1.8rem;
text-align: center;
border: 1px solid blue;
background-color: burlywood;}

.header{
grid-column: 2/-1;}

.menu{
grid-row: 1/4;}

.content{
grid-column: 2/-1;
grid-row: 2/4;}

.footer{
grid-column: 2/-1;}
```

Answer (score 1):

You've set the `.content` area to expand to row 3:

```
.content {
    grid-column: 2/-1;
    grid-row: 2/4; }   <-- spans across rows 2 and 3
```

That means that the `.footer` area is pushed into row 4, which would be lines `4/5`.

So the `.menu` area is doing exactly what you ask:

```
.menu {
    grid-row: 1/4; }   <-- spans across rows 1, 2 and 3, aligning with
                           header and content areas.
```

If you want it to be equal height with the second column (including the `.footer` area) you can either do this:

```
.menu {
    grid-row: 1/5; }
```

or this

```
.content {
    grid-column: 2/-1;
    grid-row: 2/3; }
```

Answer (score -2):

You're using a `grid` which is a great choice; but there is one grid feature, which you aren't using here, which is a tailor-made solution for the exact challenge you face.

It is called `grid-template-areas`:

```
.wrapper {
    grid-template-areas:
        'menu header'
        'menu main'
        'menu footer';
}
```

After defining the layout like that, you can simply use:

```
.header    { grid-area: header; }
.menu      { grid-area: menu;   }
.content   { grid-area: main;   }
.footer    { grid-area: footer; }
```

which is (imho) a much clearer way of doing it.

---

You can then remove all the `grid-template-columns`, `grid-template-rows`, `grid-auto-rows`, `grid-column` and `grid-row` properties that are listed in your original CSS.

---

As for how to control when the areas stretch (or not), there are basically 2 properties (with 2 values each), that let you control it all:

```
.wrapper {
    place-items:       stretch / stretch;
    place-content:     stretch / stretch;
}
```

Play around with those to your likeing.
Some of the valid values are: *center | stretch | start | end | space-around | space-between | space-evenly | ....*

Comment: I am aware of this method, but I wanted to code it using the numbers method. Could you help me with that?

Comment: It would be using those same 2 `place-items` line above. The *first* `stretch` there (which is the `align-items` value) is likely the one you need.

Comment: Why cannot I do it with numbers?

Comment: You can, i just told you how; just add `.wrapper { place-items: stretch / stretch; }`

Comment: I did add it. It changed nothing.

Comment: add your HTML to the question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240649/discussion-between-spiritmonster-and-raxi).